# not able to load the image dataset into python using tflearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tflearn

i am not able to load an image dataset into python using tflearn
    it is showing me an error...

```
TypeError: image_preloader() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_lables'
```

following is the code..

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import

import tflearn
import tensorflow as tf
from tflearn.data_utils import shuffle
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
from tflearn.data_preprocessing import ImagePreprocessing
from tflearn.data_augmentation import ImageAugmentation
import pickle

dataset_file = 'data.txt'
from tflearn.data_utils import image_preloader
X,Y=image_preloader(dataset_file, image_shape=(100,100),mode=file,categorical_lables=True,normalize=True)
img_prep = ImagePreprocessing()
img_prep.add_featurewise_zero_center()
img_prep.add_featurewise_stdnorm()
network = input_data(shape=[None, 32, 32, 3],
                     data_preprocessing=img_prep,
                 data_augmentation=img_aug)
network = conv_2d(network, 32, 3, activation='relu')
network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
network = conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation='relu')
network = conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation='relu')
network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
network = fully_connected(network, 512, activation='relu')
network = dropout(network, 0.5)
network = fully_connected(network, 2, activation='softmax')
network = regression(network, optimizer='adam',
                 loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                 learning_rate=0.001)
model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=0, checkpoint_path='bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt')
model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=100, shuffle=True, validation_set=(X_test, Y_test),
      show_metric=True, batch_size=96,
      snapshot_epoch=True,
      run_id='bird-classifier')
```

and data.txt file constains
/path/to/image class

example
img1.jpeg 0
img2.jpeg 1
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe check the spelling on `categorical_labels`.

Comment: i checked it.... no mistake in the spelling..

Comment: Then if it still doesn't work you should be getting a different error now. In the code you posted you pass `categorical_lables=True` to `image_preloader` when it expects `categorical_labels`, which is causing the unexpected keyword error.